# Maven project "AmazonS3ClientBuilder() has private access in com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, pom.xml

I've got a file and get the error mentioned in the title very early:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.Bucket;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult;
import java.io.File;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    createAndPopulateSimpleBucket();
}

public static void createAndPopulateSimpleBucket() throws Exception {
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3ClientBuilder().standard().build();
}
```

I get the error in the title when I call new AmazonS3ClientBuilder().

I'm new to Maven, and I *think* I have my pom set up correctly. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>AWSJavaHelloWorld</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.715</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm guessing something is wrong with my pom, but I can't figure out what. I **also** get the same error when I include **everything** from the AWS SDK (instead of only really including the S3 dependency).

So, can anyone spot what's wrong?

Comment: The constructor is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html) of `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` states that this class does not expose a `public` no-arg constructor. This means that you cannot invoke `new AmazonS3ClientBuilder()` from your class.

Fortunately, this class provides two `static` factory methods; one of these methods, [`AmazonS3ClientBuilder#defaultClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html#defaultClient--), creates an `AmazonS3` instance (the client), and the other method, [`AmazonS3ClientBuilder#standard`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3ClientBuilder.html#standard--), creates an instance of the builder.

Knowing this, you can replace your code with one of the following snippets:

```
public static void createAndPopulateSimpleBucket() throws Exception {
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
}
```

Or:

```
public static void createAndPopulateSimpleBucket() throws Exception {
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
}
```

Comment: This was it - thank you very much! What I thought was a problem with my dependencies was just simple syntax. Thanks again!